# How to show a loading message while preloading images in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to preload all the images I need

```
var cache = [];
function preloadImages() {
    var i;

    $("#loading").html("loading...");
    for (i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
        var src = source.replace("###", i);

        var cacheImage = document.createElement("img");
        cacheImage.src = src;

        cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
    $("#loading").html("loading completed");
}
```

And with that $("#loading").html stuff I was expecting to wait untill the loop ends to change the content, but it does not happen. It writes almost instantaneously "loading complete", while firebug tells me that the images are still downloading.

How can I make this work as expected? Why is this not working as one may expect?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for stating 2 clear questions in your first SO question! Bravo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a images remaining counter and use load event of image tag to decrement this counter. When the image count is 0 that means all the images are download then you can show the loading completed message.

```
var cache = [];
function preloadImages() {
    var i, imagesRemaining = 180;

    $("#loading").html("loading...");
    for (i = 0; i <= 180; i++) {
        var src = source.replace("###", i);

        var cacheImage = document.createElement("img");
        $(cacheImage).bind('load abort error', function(){ 

           if(imagesRemaining-- == 0){
              $("#loading").html("loading completed");
           } 

        });
        cacheImage.src = src;

        cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an explanation and I'll switch the -1 to a +1. Just dumping code doesn't help new users learn.

Comment: My bad, I added the explaination.

Comment: Yes! And it works! It allows me to do exactly what I want to.
Thank you for the explanation and thanks also to zzzBov :)

Comment: Uhm, with the code you added we are adding an event handler, right? When the event raises, the handler decreases the counter "imagesRemaining", that is not decremented directly in the loop, am I right?

Comment: Yes, it will be decremented on every image load/abort or error event.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this not working as one may expect?

Because your code is simply creating the DOM elements inside the loop then exiting immediately. Thus, your "loading" message will be replaced as soon as the `<img>` elements are created (this is very quick).

At the same time the browser will be asynchronously fetching the images specified (much slower), but your code has already finished by then.

> How can I make this work as expected?

You would need to use some other means, such as AJAX, to get the images so that you can have control and be notified when they have been received, then you can update your progress message appropriately.

Try: [Most efficient way to GET images using jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884597/most-efficient-way-to-get-images-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, now I see why it was exiting before to load images.